# How to scale an image beyond its original dimension

Tags: html, css

I am working on the Colmar University assignment at Codecademy. I am testing the website on a 34" monitor with growing/shrinking the window to check the website is behaving nicely at all screen widths.

When growing the window to a width of approx. more than 1900px the banner-image stops to increase in size.

I assume that this is caused by the dimensions of the picture (1104x816). The banner section with the image has 60% max-width.

I know fixed the problem by increasing the original dimensions of the picture so that it continues to increase in size.

My question is: is this the way to do it or is there a better way?

First tried flex-grow: 1.

Then tried empty  with image as background-image but that gave me issues with height and I seem to remember not to use empty 's

Then resized the original dimensions of the picture to accomodate for larges screen sizes. That worked but not sure there is a better way.

```
HTML 5:
<div class="banner">
  <div class="banner-img-container">
    <img src="./images/banner.jpg" alt="students learning">
  </div>

  <div class="banner-text-container">
    <h1>Learn something new everyday</h1>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h3>
    <div class="banner-button">
      <p><a href="#">Start here</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

CSS:
.banner {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
}

.banner-img-container {
    padding: 32px 24px;
    max-width: 60%;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.banner-img-container img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.banner-text-container {
    padding: 32px 24px;
    max-width: 40%;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expand the size of the image by adjusting the width and allowing the height to scale accordingly.

```
img { width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

```css
.banner {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
}

.banner-img-container {
    padding: 32px 24px;
    max-width: 60%;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.banner-img-container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.banner-text-container {
    padding: 32px 24px;
    max-width: 40%;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="banner-img-container">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1104x816" alt="students learning">
  </div>

  <div class="banner-text-container">
    <h1>Learn something new everyday</h1>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h3>
    <div class="banner-button">
      <p><a href="#">Start here</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an `<img>` tag you can use purely css properties:

```css
.banner{
    background-img: url("./images/banner.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
}
```

See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) for more about css backgrounds.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. So are you saying to use an empty <div> and then set background-picture in css? How would you control the height dynamically (when growing/shrinking the window) as the height of the banner-img-container flex box is then determined by the banner-text-container because it is empty. Wouldn't setting a specific height mess up the automatic resizing?